# Heroku - Make an already created database a follower to another one

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

When I follow the steps to create a follower in heroku official site it shows this command:

`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-2 --follow HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL_URL`

The thing is that I already created the database, and now I want to make it a follower.

I would expect something like this:

`heroku pg:follow <DATABASE_URL_THAT_WILL_FOLLOW> <DATABASE_URL_THAT_WILL_BE_FOLLOWED>`

Is that posible in heroku? Thanks!